# Cannot compare a converted variable in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database I have a column `Period` of type `int` and values are in YYYYMM format e.g. 201709. There is another column called `Date` of type `datetime` and values are e.g. 2015-07-31 00:00:00.000. I want to select rows where these two columns are equal e.g. `Period` (201507) = `Date` (201507).

I have tried this code:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM db
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Period) = LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, (DATEADD(month, -11, Date)), 112), 6)
```

Doing this returns 0 rows.

I have also tried:

```
WHERE Period = CONVERT(INT, (LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, (DATEADD(month, -11, Date)), 112), 6)))
```

Of course I did in the first attempt:

```
WHERE Period = LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, (DATEADD(month, -11, Date)), 112), 6)))
```

I have checked in the database there are rows where the values should match.

What should be done to retrieve rows I desire?

Comment: Check your assumptions.  What you have should work.  It can be simplified, but that won't solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do would be to extract the Year and month components from your date field and format them into an integer.

```
WHERE Period = YEAR(Date) * 100 + MONTH(Date)
```

Comment: this is simple and works, do you know why my attempts with the left and convert didn't work?

Comment: Never could really make heads or tails of why you were subtracting 11 months from your date field {DATEADD(MONTH,-11,date)}, but otherwise it should have worked.  I haven't built any harnesses or tested this, but in my experience comparing two varchar fields is slightly less efficient than comparing integer fields.  I'm not sure if the overhead of the Year and Month functions would be greater than, equal to, or less than the overhead of the converts, but I suspect it would be quicker in my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `Period` to the correct format to match the `nvarchar` format for the second comparison:

There are several ways you could do this, for one way, try this in place of `CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Period)` and see if that works for you:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Year(Period)) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Month(Period))
```

Comment: Apologies, I missed that.  I am also puzzled why your formatting of the date field didn't work, but the first answer at least gives you a good alternative.